# Using observe_field on an field inside a fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to observe a field that get generated inside a fields_for loop.

The thing is that the id of that field is generated dynamically.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<% form_for @exp, :url => {:action => "update"} do |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for:patterns do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'pattern_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_pattern_fields.html.erb**

```
Pattern: <%= f.select(:LC_PATTERN, [['stripes', 'stripes'],
                                  ['dots', 'dots'],
                                  ['lines', 'lines'],
                                 ],{ :prompt => "Please select"}
                                 ) %>

<%= observe_field("------", :frequency => 1,
:with => "'id='+value", :function => 'alert(value)')%>
```

My question is how do i get the id of the field inside the fields_for tag.

Comment: why you don't set it manually?

Comment: There are several pattern fields(with different ids) which are generated in that form. How am i supposed to manually set the id for each pattern observe_field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. Found this solution on the internet...Hope it might be of help to someone else.

In your application_helper.rb, add the following functions:

```
def sanitized_object_name(object_name)
  object_name.gsub(/\]\[|[^-a-zA-Z0-9:.]/,"_").sub(/_$/,"")
end

def sanitized_method_name(method_name)
  method_name.sub(/\?$/, "")
end

def form_tag_id(object_name, method_name)
  "#{sanitized_object_name(object_name.to_s)}_#{sanitized_method_name(method_name.to_s)}"
end
```

You can then view the id of the fields generated inside 'fields_for' by using the following code:

```
<%=form_tag_id(f.object_name, :LC_PATTERN) %>
```

Comment: how can i use this with nested_forms?